# Is there any possible way to ignore accents in a worksheet's name when you're trying to index/select a worksheet in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, diacritics

The problem is that when I had MS Office 2013 I could use letters in Excel worksheets' names like "Ó, Ő, Ű" etc. but I had an OS and software update recently at my company (from Win7 to Win10, and from MS Office 2013 to 2016), and now some character with such diacritical marks has been replaced with letters without these marks like "O, U".

For example I had a worksheet called: **Sheet1 (Összeszámolás)** in MS Office 2013

Now that worksheet is called: **Sheet1 (Osszeszámolás)** in MS Office 2016

If I use the lastly mentioned worksheet name when I'm calling a worksheet then the ones who have MS Office 2013 won't be able to operate with the excel (VBA doesn't find the actual sheet).

Indexing with worksheet numbers doesn't work (e.g **Sheets(2).Select**) because MS Office 2013 indexes differently than version 2016. **Sheets(2).Select** selects the 2nd worksheet in MSO 2013 but in 2016 it selects the 3rd one..

Am I able to make excel ignore the accents so **Sheets("Osszeszamolas")** would be able to select  either **Sheet1 (Összeszámolás)** and **Sheet1 (Osszeszámolás)**

Note: I've tried to look for language options, but there ain't any options that could handle these specific accents..

Comment: Does the worksheet `CodeName` property exhibit the same discrepancies with accents/diacritics? NB, your assertion that `Sheets(2)` selects the *third* sheet in 2016 is not correct. Sheets are still indexed as a 1-based Collection.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue, using **Összeszámolás** (copied and pasted directly from your post). It does not convert when opening in Excel 2016; it keeps the same content. I did nothing to support other languages - my tests were done on a standard O365 installation in English (US) Windows. Also, your assertion that tab indexing changed is incorrect; sheets are still numbered starting at 1, just as they were in prior versions of Excel.

Comment: Well that is strange.. I can't refer to any other people's experience but mine. I don't know what am I doing wrong.. I open an excel made in Office 2013 with Office 2016 and it renames the freaking worksheets with removing some specific diactretical marks (like Ö to O)..

And I think I've miswritten that Sheet(2) would select the 3rd worksheet.
It selects the 1st worksheet in version 2016 while in version 2013 it selects the 2nd...

Comment: Interesting that it appears that only the "Ö" seems to have been changed, at least based on your post. Are you certain that it isn't a font size vs tab height display issue in 2016 that's just cutting the diacritic off the top, but that it's actually there?

Comment: Do you have code that actually generates an Index Out of Range error? Or are you just guessing that there will be an error?

Comment: Wouldn't it be more likely that a different locale was used for the Office installation by mistake?

Comment: Ö, Ő, Ü, Ű <-- these are the characters that are touched. No, I've written the names in cells and it seems that these letters were converted to non diacritic letters.

Comment: There is not any error, Sheet(1).Activate activates the 2nd worksheet, like the indexing offset would be set to "0". So the Sheet(0).Activate activates the 1st worksheet.. I've only seen something like this in SQL database or something before..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to VBA, and rename the VBA name of the worksheet in the there, and use that name.

So go to VBA,press Ctrl+R, locate the sheet, click once, press F4 if necessary to popup the properties, change the property Name (Not "(Name)" but "Name").

From now on, you can use that name in your VBA-code to refer to that worksheet-object directly. So if the name you give is "ThisIsMyVBANameForThisWorksheet", you can code in VBA with

```
ThisIsMyVBANameForThisWorksheet.Activate
```

If this is no option, you can use the default VBA names for the sheets. In English office, these are Sheet1, Sheet2, etc. (If you use multiple languages of Office within your company, that is not an option either.)

So

```
Sheet1.Activate
```

Comment: To be clear: It is NOT Sheets("ThisIsMyVBANameForThisWorksheet").Activate. That won't work.

Comment: Then the other ones who refers to this specific excel workbook will get an error that VBA couldn't find the actual worksheet.
It's a big company, I couldn't do it.

Comment: Oh. Then just use Sheet1.Activate, Sheet2.Activate. (Or whatever your language of Office is and whatever you want to do with the sheet.)

Problem with that is that if there are multiple languages of Office, there  will be different names, because the default names are localised.

Comment: I've already told why indexing like that wouldn't work... somehow in my case Sheets(1).Select wants to select the 2nd sheet....

Comment: Laczko, Of course I am EXACTLY giving you the opportunity NOT to use that indexing. I can read. ;) Please do read better. I updated the answer as well. There is NO indexing, but the use of DIRECT names..

Comment: The names happen to have a number in them, but that is something COMPLETELY different than indexing.

Comment: Glad it did! Of course, my solution will 'Sheet1' and 'Sheet2' only work in specific cases where the sheets you want to reference always have been the first and second sheet. If you have three sheets, and remove the second one, in VBA, you will have Sheet1 and Sheet3, equivalent to Worksheets(1) and Worksheets(2). So  Worksheets(2).Name would give "Sheet3. "Ah. Logic. ;) If you are aware of that and it is no problem, you're good to go.

Comment: I'll consider this while working at my projects, Thank you again! Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

If above doesn't work/suffice I also have a bit more robust solution:

```
Function ReliableWorksheet(x) As Worksheet
    Dim W As Worksheet
    For Each W In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If W.Index = x Then Set ReliableWorksheet = W
    Next
End Function
```

And then use

```
ReliableWorksheet(1).Activate
```

This should work on all office versions, in all languages, but I cannot test it  other than O2013.